# installing PHP APC extension on windows

Tags: php, apc

I want to install the APC extension for PHP. I've got to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php) page and I'm a little stuck. 
I've downloaded a file from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/apc), which gives me a APC-3.1.9.tgz file.
I've extracted the file. However from the page I've mentioned above, I'm given the impression I need to load a .dll file.

I'm lost and confused, what should I be doing?

- **OS:** Windows Vista
- **Server:** Apache
- **PHP:** 5.3.5

Comment: Thought this might help A DLL for APC on windows? http://pecl.php.net/package/APC/3.1.13/windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php

> A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the
>   [building on Windows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php) section.

In other words: no easy way on Windows

Comment: Hello there, I went through the documents and followed step-by-step and stuck at step 12 which says **in the same directory (C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86) there is a “deps” folder, extract any of your required libraries inside that folder (see http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs) but make sure their top-level contains /include and /lib (some of them have an extra directory level in there)** What does the **extract any of your required libraries inside that folder** means? I dont know which library I need. Oh well I am trying to install APC I doubt he means it or that site doesnt have it

Comment: @dev2dev: I think you can safely start a new question about this.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the compiled dll from [downloads.php.net](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the resource. I've tried a few of these out but I keep getting a warning message saying "Unable to initialize module. Module complied with module API=2006013. PHP compiled with module API=20090626" Any idea what this means?

Comment: Apparently the DLL was compiled with Visual Studio 2006 while PHP with Visual Studio 2009.

Comment: Also, this link doesn't have the latest 3.1.9 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the [file](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86.zip) from above mentioned http://downloads.php.net/pierre/. The zip contains two folders: "nts" and "ts" (probably "tread safe" and "non thread safe") with php_apc.dll file.

You must put this file in your PHP extensions folder (for exemple c:\wamp\bin\php5.4.1\ext) and edit PHP.ini file to add or uncomment the line:

```
extension=php_apc.dll
```

After restarting web service (Apache, IIS, etc.) you can check the PHP configuration with 
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see if "apc" block appeared

Answer (score 1):

Here's hoping people looking for APC for Windows are still checking this post.

I just found APC 3.1.9 for Windows here:

http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html

Confirmed working on Apache 2, PHP 5.3.8, Windows 7 (32-bit).

Answer (score 0):

try this Alternative PHP Cache (APC) 3.1.9 extension

https://code.google.com/p/xampp-php-extensions/downloads/detail?name=php_apc.dll&can=2&q=